# specific title for each button in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have an `UIWebView` page with one `UIScrollView`, inside of my `UIScrollView` I have `UIImage` and buttons
I want to set specific title for each button from my xml file, Would you please give me some hint for implementing this?

rightnow I can get the first name from xml but it"s set for all

my scrollView with Button and images:

```
const NSUInteger kNumImages = 5;



scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;

// load all the images 
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i<= kNumImages; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag = i;  
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];



UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    appDelegate = (testAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    Presentation1Name *aSlide = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@" %@", aSlide.slideLabel );

    [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:aSlide.slideLabel]  
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     btn.frame = rect;
     [btn setTag:i];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)  
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [imageView addSubview:btn];



}

[self layoutScrollImages];
```

}

for adding title for all button I'm using code

```
   [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:aSlide.slideLabel]  
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but for each button I want to have specific title from xml file

Thanks in advance!

Here is my xml file:

```
 <Presentation label="presentation1">
<slides>
    <slide index="0" label="slide1" identifier="Slide1Name" />

    <slide index="1" label="something" identifier="Slide2Name" />

</slides>
 </Presentation>
```

**Edit:**

When I add  Presentation1Name *aSlide = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:0]; objectAtIndex to i I will get this error

when I add objectAtIndex: i
process terminated *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument' 
** First throw call stack: 
(0x1c95012 0x10d2e7e 0x1c94deb 0xae97f5 0xae9774 0x3d64 0x4723 0x10e6705 0x1d920 0x1d8b8 0xde671 0xdebcf 0xddd38 0x4d33f 0x4d552 0x2b3aa 0x1ccf8 0x1bf0df9 0x1bf0ad0 0x1c0abf5 0x1c0a962 0x1c3bbb6 0x1c3af44 0x1c3ae1b 0x1bef7e3 0x1bef668 0x1a65c 0x295d 0x2885 0x1) 
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception 
(lldb)

and it"s because of

-[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'

after that I change 5 t0 2 since I have just 2 label in my xml file

```
const NSUInteger kNumImages= 2;
```

and also change for (i = 1; i<= kNumImages; i++) to

```
for (i = 0; i> kNumImages; i++)
```

but still it"not working correctly

My question is How can I do this

```
appDelegate.books count should be equal to kNumImages
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyButton %d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

Store all button names in **NSMutableArray** and then later use it

For example like this:

```
 NSMutableArray *arrNames = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Dog",@"Cat",......,nil]; //fill your array

 [btn setTitle:[arrNames objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Second option is to use @Andrey Chernukha justed in his answer

Comment: I have different button, since i get title button from xml file, and for each xml I have different button and title, can I still use this method?

Comment: extract button title from xml file and store in mutable array

Comment: I will get everything from xml file, when I use this line [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithString:aSlide.slideLabel] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 I have one name for all of my buttons, how can I get name for each from xml? can you help me